# How do I linearize this system to achieve the stated result?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, control-theory

I am trying to linearize this system, but I am having difficulty matching my result to the stated result because of the complexity of the terms.

The system is given by:

$f(x,u) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    \dfrac{x_{2}}{x_{2} + K}x_{1} - Dx_{1}\\
    -\dfrac{x_{2}}{x_{2} + K}x_{1} + D(1-x_{2})
\end{bmatrix}$

There are two equilibria, I am interested in linearizing about $x_{e} = [0 
 \ 1]^{T}$

The stated solution is:

$\frac{\partial{f(x,u)}}{\partial{x}} = $
$\begin{bmatrix}
    \dfrac{x_{2e}}{x_{2e} + K} - D & \dfrac{Kx_{1e}}{(x_{2e} + K)^{2}} \\
    -\dfrac{x_{2e}}{x_{2e} + K} & -\dfrac{Kx_{1e}}{x_{2e} + K} - D
\end{bmatrix} |x_{e}$

With substitution of $x_{e}$ and K = $\dfrac{1-D}{D}$ leading to:

$\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 \\
    -D & - D
\end{bmatrix}$

I am skeptical about the result, to me it seems the linearization requires to use of quotient/product rule which generates extra terms that do not drop out.

Comment: Have you tried doing the partial derivative yourself?

Answer (score 1):

The Jacobian is given as:

$$ \boldsymbol{J}=\left[ \begin {array}{cc} {\frac {x_{2}}{x_{2}+K}}-D&{\frac {x_{1}}{x
_{2}+K}}-{\frac {x_{2}\,x_{1}}{ \left( x_{2}+K \right) ^{2}}}
\\-{\frac {x_{2}}{x_{2}+K}}&-{\frac {x_{1}}{x_{2}+K
}}+{\frac {x_{2}\,x_{1}}{ \left( x_{2}+K \right) ^{2}}}-D\end {array}
 \right] 
$$

Evaluated at $x_1=0$ and $x_2=1$ you will obtain:

$$\boldsymbol{A}_{\text{eq}}(K,D)=\left[ \begin {array}{cc}  \left( 1+K \right) ^{-1}-D&0
\\ - \left( 1+K \right) ^{-1}&-D\end {array}
 \right].$$

Using $K=(1-D)/D$:
$$\boldsymbol{A}_{\text{eq}}(D)=\left[ \begin {array}{cc} 0&0\\ -D&-D\end {array}
 \right] 
$$

Comment: Thanks! This makes me feel better, the intermediate solution was incorrect which has happened quite a few times. I appreciate the help.